# MongoDb insert via Node.js Native Driver not inserting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get some data to save into MongoDb. I followed the following example beforehand and verified that it works, however now that I'm trying to write my own test app using this "format" it's not working. MongoDb does not throw any errors and I can even retrieve the doc _id from the insert callback. However when I go into the Mongo shell, the collection doesn't even exist let alone the document.

Here's the example I followed originally just so you can get a feel for the way I tried to mimic for my own test app:

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

Below is my attempt that is failing. Thanks for any help!

Here's my DB code:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    Connection = require('mongodb').Connection,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    BSON = require('mongodb').BSON,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


Repository = function(host, port){
    this.db = new Db('test-mongo-db', new Server(host, port, {safe: true}, {auto_reconnect:true}, {}));
    this.db.open(function(){

        console.log('db open');

    });
};

Repository.prototype.getCollection = function(callback){
    this.db.collection('owners', function(error, owners_collection){
        if (error) callback(error);
        else
            callback(null, owners_collection);
    });
};

Repository.prototype.createOwner = function(owner, callback){
    this.getCollection(function(error, owners_collection){

        if (error) callback(error);
        else {

            owners_collection.insert(owner, function(error, doc){

                if (error) callback(error);
                else {
                    console.log('insert was successful: ' + doc[0]['_id']);
                    callback(null, owner);
                }
            });

        }

    });
};

exports.Repository = Repository;
```

Here's the code that's calling it:

```
var Repository = require('../repositories/Repository').Repository;

exports.createOwner = function(req, res){


    var owner = {

        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        firstName : req.body.firstName,
        lastName : req.body.lastName,

        schools : []

    };

    var repository = new Repository('localhost', 27017);

    repository.createOwner(owner, function(error, docs){

        if (error) console.log('saving owner failed : ' + error);
        else {
            console.log('saving owner successful');
            res.redirect('/');
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: Can you attach your console output as well?

Comment: Hello! There are no errors. The only console output are the success messages you see in the above code. Earlier I literally put console logs everywhere and everything seems to be hitting, just not truly saving.

Comment: I'm more curious of messages are out of order, rather than if there are errors.

Comment: ah I see...here's the output. It does seem out of order:

before insert,
inside insert,
insert was successful: 51a90c931726ed081d000001,
saving owner successful,
POST /owner/create 302 57ms - 58b,
db open,
GET / 304 42ms,
GET /styles/style.css 304 4ms,

Comment: You are not waiting for the driver to actually finish connecting before executing your operations so it's likely your inserts are failing silently, also update to the latest driver as there has been a fair bit of bug fixes since then.

Answer (score 0):

If @cristkv is right, you can try to add optional parameter write concern in the insert operation:

`owners_collection.insert(owner, {w:1}, function(error, doc){`

sources:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#insert

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/